# Why does adding `--no-update-dependencies` add more updates with conda?

Tags: python, conda

When I do `conda install spacy --no-update-dependencies`, `conda` wants to make more updates than when I do `conda install spacy`. Why?

However, I read on https://conda.io/docs/commands/conda-install.html:

> ```
>   --no-update-dependencies, --no-update-deps
>           Don't update dependencies (default: False).
> ```

I would have assumed that adding `--no-update-dependencies` would result in fewer updates with conda.

`conda install spacy`:

```
C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts>conda install spacy --update-dependencies
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    cymem:      1.31.2-py36_vc14_0     conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    dill:       0.2.6-py36_0           conda-forge
    ftfy:       4.4.2-py36_0           conda-forge
    murmurhash: 0.26.4-py36_vc14_0     conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    plac:       0.9.6-py36_0
    preshed:    1.0.0-py36_vc14_0      conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    pyreadline: 2.1-py36_0
    regex:      2017.04.05-py36_0      conda-forge
    spacy:      1.8.2-np112py36_vc14_0 conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    termcolor:  1.1.0-py36_1           conda-forge
    thinc:      6.5.2-np112py36_vc14_0 conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    tqdm:       4.14.0-py36_0          conda-forge
    ujson:      1.35-py36_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:      4.3.21-py36_0                                                                                  --> 4.3.22-py36_0 conda-forge

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

    conda-env:  2.6.0-0                file:///C:/Users/john/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Scripts --> 2.6.0-0       conda-forge

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

`conda install spacy --no-update-dependencies`:

```
C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\Scripts>conda install spacy --no-update-dependencies
Fetching package metadata .............
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    boto3:              1.4.4-py36_0           conda-forge
    botocore:           1.5.55-py36_0          conda-forge
    cymem:              1.31.2-py36_vc14_0     conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    dill:               0.2.6-py36_0           conda-forge
    ftfy:               4.4.2-py36_0           conda-forge
    imageio:            2.2.0-py36_0           conda-forge
    jmespath:           0.9.3-py36_0           conda-forge
    libiconv:           1.14-vc14_4            conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    libxml2:            2.9.4-vc14_4           conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    libxslt:            1.1.29-vc14_5          conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    mccabe:             0.6.1-py36_0           conda-forge
    murmurhash:         0.26.4-py36_vc14_0     conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    pandoc:             1.19.2-0               conda-forge
    plac:               0.9.6-py36_0
    preshed:            1.0.0-py36_vc14_0      conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    pyreadline:         2.1-py36_0
    regex:              2017.04.05-py36_0      conda-forge
    s3fs:               0.1.1-py36_0           conda-forge
    s3transfer:         0.1.10-py36_1          conda-forge
    spacy:              1.8.2-np112py36_vc14_0 conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    termcolor:          1.1.0-py36_1           conda-forge
    thinc:              6.5.2-np112py36_vc14_0 conda-forge                                                             [vc14]
    tqdm:               4.14.0-py36_0          conda-forge
    ujson:              1.35-py36_0
    vc:                 14-0                   conda-forge
    webencodings:       0.5-py36_0             conda-forge
    yaml:               0.1.6-vc14_0           conda-forge                                                             [vc14]

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda:              4.3.21-py36_0                                                                                  --> 4.3.22-py36_0      conda-forge

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

    alabaster:          0.7.10-py36_0                                                                                  --> 0.7.10-py36_0      conda-forge
    anaconda-client:    1.6.3-py36_0                                                                                   --> 1.6.3-py36_0       conda-forge
    asn1crypto:         0.22.0-py36_0                                                                                  --> 0.22.0-py36_0      conda-forge
    astropy:            1.3.2-np112py36_0                                                                              --> 1.3.2-np112py36_0  conda-forge
    bleach:             1.5.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 1.5.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    cffi:               1.10.0-py36_0                                                                                  --> 1.10.0-py36_0      conda-forge
    click:              6.7-py36_0                                                                                     --> 6.7-py36_0         conda-forge
    colorama:           0.3.9-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.3.9-py36_0       conda-forge
    conda-env:          2.6.0-0                file:///C:/Users/john/AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Scripts --> 2.6.0-0            conda-forge
    contextlib2:        0.5.5-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.5.5-py36_0       conda-forge
    curl:               7.52.1-vc14_0                                                                                  [vc14] --> 7.52.1-vc14_0      conda-forge [vc14]
    cycler:             0.10.0-py36_0                                                                                  --> 0.10.0-py36_0      conda-forge
    cython:             0.25.2-py36_0                                                                                  --> 0.25.2-py36_0      conda-forge
    cytoolz:            0.8.2-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.8.2-py36_0       conda-forge
    decorator:          4.0.11-py36_0                                                                                  --> 4.0.11-py36_0      conda-forge
    distributed:        1.16.3-py36_0                                                                                  --> 1.16.3-py36_0      conda-forge
    docutils:           0.13.1-py36_0                                                                                  --> 0.13.1-py36_0      conda-forge
    entrypoints:        0.2.2-py36_1                                                                                   --> 0.2.2-py36_1       conda-forge
    et_xmlfile:         1.0.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 1.0.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    greenlet:           0.4.12-py36_0                                                                                  --> 0.4.12-py36_0      conda-forge
    html5lib:           0.999-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.999-py36_0       conda-forge
    idna:               2.5-py36_0                                                                                     --> 2.5-py36_0         conda-forge
    imagesize:          0.7.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.7.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    ipykernel:          4.6.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 4.6.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    ipython:            5.3.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 5.3.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    ipython_genutils:   0.2.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.2.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    ipywidgets:         6.0.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 6.0.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    isort:              4.2.5-py36_0                                                                                   --> 4.2.5-py36_0       conda-forge
    jdcal:              1.3-py36_0                                                                                     --> 1.3-py36_0         conda-forge
    jpeg:               9b-vc14_0                                                                                      [vc14] --> 9b-vc14_0          conda-forge [vc14]
    jupyter_client:     5.0.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 5.0.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    jupyter_console:    5.1.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 5.1.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    jupyter_core:       4.3.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 4.3.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    lazy-object-proxy:  1.2.2-py36_0                                                                                   --> 1.2.2-py36_0       conda-forge
    locket:             0.2.0-py36_1                                                                                   --> 0.2.0-py36_1       conda-forge
    lxml:               3.7.3-py36_0                                                                                   --> 3.7.3-py36_0       conda-forge
    mistune:            0.7.4-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.7.4-py36_0       conda-forge
    mpmath:             0.19-py36_1                                                                                    --> 0.19-py36_1        conda-forge
    msgpack-python:     0.4.8-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.4.8-py36_0       conda-forge
    multipledispatch:   0.4.9-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.4.9-py36_0       conda-forge
    nbconvert:          5.1.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 5.1.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    nbformat:           4.3.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 4.3.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    networkx:           1.11-py36_0                                                                                    --> 1.11-py36_0        conda-forge
    notebook:           5.0.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 5.0.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    numexpr:            2.6.2-np112py36_0                                                                              --> 2.6.2-np112py36_0  conda-forge
    numpydoc:           0.6.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.6.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    olefile:            0.44-py36_0                                                                                    --> 0.44-py36_0        conda-forge
    packaging:          16.8-py36_0                                                                                    --> 16.8-py36_0        conda-forge
    pandas:             0.20.1-np112py36_0                                                                             --> 0.20.1-np112py36_0 conda-forge
    pandocfilters:      1.4.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 1.4.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    partd:              0.3.8-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.3.8-py36_0       conda-forge
    pathlib2:           2.2.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 2.2.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    patsy:              0.4.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.4.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    prompt_toolkit:     1.0.14-py36_0                                                                                  --> 1.0.14-py36_0      conda-forge
    py:                 1.4.33-py36_0                                                                                  --> 1.4.33-py36_0      conda-forge
    pycparser:          2.17-py36_0                                                                                    --> 2.17-py36_0        conda-forge
    pyflakes:           1.5.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 1.5.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    pygments:           2.2.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 2.2.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    pylint:             1.6.4-py36_1                                                                                   --> 1.6.4-py36_1       conda-forge
    pyqt:               5.6.0-py36_2                                                                                   --> 5.6.0-py36_2       conda-forge
    pytest:             3.0.7-py36_0                                                                                   --> 3.0.7-py36_0       conda-forge
    python-dateutil:    2.6.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 2.6.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    pytz:               2017.2-py36_0                                                                                  --> 2017.2-py36_0      conda-forge
    pywavelets:         0.5.2-np112py36_0                                                                              --> 0.5.2-np112py36_0  conda-forge
    pyyaml:             3.12-py36_0                                                                                    --> 3.12-py36_0        conda-forge
    pyzmq:              16.0.2-py36_0                                                                                  --> 16.0.2-py36_0      conda-forge
    qtawesome:          0.4.4-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.4.4-py36_0       conda-forge
    qtconsole:          4.3.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 4.3.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    qtpy:               1.2.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 1.2.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    scikit-image:       0.13.0-np112py36_0                                                                             --> 0.13.0-np112py36_0 conda-forge
    seaborn:            0.7.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.7.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    singledispatch:     3.4.0.3-py36_0                                                                                 --> 3.4.0.3-py36_0     conda-forge
    snowballstemmer:    1.2.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 1.2.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    sphinx:             1.5.6-py36_0                                                                                   --> 1.5.6-py36_0       conda-forge
    spyder:             3.1.4-py36_0                                                                                   --> 3.1.4-py36_0       conda-forge
    statsmodels:        0.8.0-np112py36_0                                                                              --> 0.8.0-np112py36_0  conda-forge
    sympy:              1.0-py36_0                                                                                     --> 1.0-py36_0         conda-forge
    tblib:              1.3.2-py36_0                                                                                   --> 1.3.2-py36_0       conda-forge
    testpath:           0.3-py36_0                                                                                     --> 0.3-py36_0         conda-forge
    toolz:              0.8.2-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.8.2-py36_0       conda-forge
    tornado:            4.5.1-py36_0                                                                                   --> 4.5.1-py36_0       conda-forge
    traitlets:          4.3.2-py36_0                                                                                   --> 4.3.2-py36_0       conda-forge
    vs2015_runtime:     14.0.25123-0                                                                                   --> 14.0.25123-0       conda-forge
    wcwidth:            0.1.7-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.1.7-py36_0       conda-forge
    werkzeug:           0.12.2-py36_0                                                                                  --> 0.12.2-py36_0      conda-forge
    wheel:              0.29.0-py36_0                                                                                  --> 0.29.0-py36_0      conda-forge
    widgetsnbextension: 2.0.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 2.0.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    xlrd:               1.0.0-py36_0                                                                                   --> 1.0.0-py36_0       conda-forge
    xlsxwriter:         0.9.6-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.9.6-py36_0       conda-forge
    zict:               0.1.2-py36_0                                                                                   --> 0.1.2-py36_0       conda-forge
    zlib:               1.2.8-vc14_3                                                                                   [vc14] --> 1.2.8-vc14_3       conda-forge [vc14]

Proceed ([y]/n)? n
```

Comment: Do you have `strict_channel_priority` or related channel configuration set in your conda config?